# Encode background-image property for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image, encode

I'm having a bit a difficulty displaying images using the `background-image` property in Internet Explorer. For example, I transform this url

> DLH_747-8I_1443_RC022_0003 - Copy (2).jpg

with

```
url = encodeURI(url).replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29');
```

to which it becomes

> DLH_747-8I_1443_RC022_0003%20-%20Copy%20%282%29.jpg

The transformed URLs work just fine with `background-image` in Chrome and Firefox, but of course IE is giving me trouble.

Is there a special way that IE encodes URLs for `url()` based properties such as `background-image`?

Comment: All versions that I've tried (8 - 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#url) defined the url as having the following rules concerning escaping:

> Parentheses, commas, whitespace characters, single quotes (') and double quotes (") appearing in a URL must be escaped with a backslash: '(', ')', '\,'.

What that means is that while IE is technically non-conformant on its URL handling overall, it  does technically conform to the spec insofar as it recognizes `DLH_747-8I_1443_RC022_0003\ -\ Copy\ \(2\).jpg` as a valid URL.

Comment: Thanks! This works. I found out the underlying issue was that the images were an improper format of JPEG (they were png, saved with the extension jpg) so IE didn't like that.